# Can't install gcc, you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, gcc

I'm trying to install gcc, but I keep getting this message:

```
~$ sudo apt install gcc make gdb valgrind git

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gcc : Depends: gcc-9 (>= 9.3.0-3~) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                   libc-dev
 valgrind : Depends: libc6-dbg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` and try installing these packages again

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I tired to do that, but I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sudo apt -f install
```

and rerun your command for more info visit this
[site](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages)